# @babel/preset-typescript can not be found after upgrading React Native from 0.67.4 to 0.68.0

Tags: react-native, babeljs

After upgrading React Native from 0.67.4 to 0.68.0 on Big Sur, `react-native run-android` shows a red screen on android studio 2021.1.1 Patch 2 emulator after launch. And can not find @babel/preset-typescript.

```
error: node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/handlers/gestures/GestureDetector.tsx: /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/handlers/gestures/GestureDetector.tsx: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-typescript'
Require stack:
- /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
- /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js
- /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.js
- /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
 BUNDLE  ./index.js
```

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Here is the portion of `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ethersproject/shims": "^5.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.2.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "ethers": "^5.6.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.0",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.14.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.5.1",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-encrypted-storage": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.7.3",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-redash": "^16.2.3",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "rn-alioss": "^0.2.5",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
```

I can `yarn add @babel/preset-typescript -D` but is there way to fix the error without explicitly adding @babel/preset-typescript?

Comment: Removed and add react-native-gesture-handler again and the error is the same.